# How to append button into popup in leaflet draw?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, leaflet-draw

**I want button inside popup to make some action on popup attached layer.**

```
 L.marker(coors[i], { icon })
          .addTo(this.drawnItem)
          .bindPopup(this._getCustomIcon(mix))
          .openPopup();
```

**Below my _getCustomIcon()**

```
 _getCustomIcon = value => {
    let delLayer = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    delLayer.innerHTML = "Delete";
    let CustomPopup = L.popup({ className: "customPopup" }).setContent(
      `<p> ${value}</p> ${delLayer}` //here is error
    );
    return CustomPopup;
  };
```

Comment: If you are using `reactjs` then I would suggest you to use `react-leaflet` (https://react-leaflet.js.org/). It will make eveything easier.  To modify marker it is easy as this `<Marker position={position} >
                <Popup>{city_name} centre
                        <Button>Test Button</Button>
                </Popup>
            </Marker>`

Comment: You are mixing strings with objects, try `<p> ${value}</p> <button>Delete</button>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this code

```
 _getCustomIcon = value => {
    let delLayer = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    delLayer.innerHTML = "Delete";
    return delLayer;
  };
```

Your mistake is creating a popup after using `bindPopup` which already creates popup!

Answer (score 1):

Here `delLayer` is an object but not a plain string. You should convert the element object to string using `.outerHTML` when you concatenate in string template literal

```
_getCustomIcon = value => {
    let delLayer = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    delLayer.innerHTML = "Delete";
    let CustomPopup = `<p> ${value}</p> ${delLayer.outerHTML}`;
    return CustomPopup;
};
```

Alternatively you may try using concatenate as a plain string like

```
let delLayer = '<button>Delete</button>'
let CustomPopup = `<p> ${value}</p> ${delLayer}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing strings with objects, try `<p> ${value}</p> <button>Delete</button>`